# What is the job of miners in Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory

Q. Is it correct to state that a Bitcoin miner has only two jobs:

- validating transactions
- creating a block to add into the blockchain

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a bitcoin miner is only concerned with creating the next block on the blockchain, through a computationally-difficult problem. It is the role of bitcoin nodes to verify this proof-of-work as they receive these newly created blocks.

As reference, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining